# What terminal command stops webrick server besides Ctrl-C?

Tags: command-line, redmine, webrick

We are using Redmine. The mysql adapter segfaults in the mornings when the first Redmine operation is attempted, e.g. clicking on the Projects menu. Redmine works perfectly after Webrick is manually restarted.

The problem is that the mysql gem was compiled against MySQL 5.0, but we are using a later MySQL version. This is what I learned on the official Redmine issue tracker. For the moment, I am not going to attempt to recompile against our version.

I have a vbscript script that can restart the server during the very early hours of the morning. The vbscript script runs a batch file containing `ruby script/server webrick -e production` which can start webrick, but if webrick is already running, the script does not make a difference. I need a command that can stop the server.

Comment: Not enough information. What causes the 'first Redmine operation'. ? 'In the morning', so if you restart it after it fails, then it works?  Why do you suspect 'Ctrl-C'. Please amend your posting to include a transcript of your use-case with exact error messages, either from cmd-line or log files. These are obscure tags, maybe you can add some more general interest tags that are still related to your issue. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when installed on a windows system - after 8 hours of activity, the mysql adapter would segfault.

The fix was to place an other mysql binary in the ruby\bin.

The issue is described in the [forum](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/11656?r=13947), and the link to an other dll is provided in the [installation manual](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Notes-on-Windows-installation).

On a side note, but not really related to this issue: The question is tagged *webrick*, be aware that you should run redmine on mongrel instead of webrick. The above linked wiki page also says:

> It is not recommended to use webrick for anything other than
>   development.

Comment: Thanks. I got the dll. I cannot wait for tomorrow morning.