# Redmine Performance Inconsistency

Tags: performance, apache, nginx, redmine, passenger

I have a redmine instance deployed on a Linux x86_64 system and I am struggle with a funny performance inconsistency issue. It behave like this:

Leave it alone for a couple of hours (no request to the application at all) then establish a connection, it takes a very long time to response to the first few requests (can be as bad as 15 seconds+, sometimes every for response at about 1 minute). After the first few requests, it performance very quickly, almost instantly where I can see from the log that it takes less than 100ms to response.

I have tried a couple of options to run it using mongrel, deployed it on passenger-Nginx, and on passenger-Apache. The behaviour simply reproduceable. I realised from the testing when it is keeping busy, there will be no problem at all.

What is it all about? How can I improve this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062563/what-terminal-command-stops-webrick-server-besides-ctrl-c - a known problem with mysql on windows, and therefore probably not related to your problem. Is there anything in the log files (mongrel logs for example) ?

Comment: Don't really see any error in the log related to the database. I also checked with [this FAQ in Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/FAQ#The-application-freeze-after-a-long-time-of-inactivity). I have MySQL/Ruby adaptor 2.8.1 since day 1, the only thing was the gem was not install by the gem command, but via executing the extconf.rb script instead.

Comment: Going through the [Passenger user guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) again, looks like there might be a chance to resolve the problem by combining the usage of PassengerPreStart, PassengerMinInstances and PassengerPoolIdleTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by the the Passenger pool idleling out. You can either increase the PassengePoolIdleTime to a larger number, or if you don't wan it to time out at all set the value to 0. An Apache config something like below should fix the issues

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/redmine/site/public
    ServerName example.com
    PassengerPoolIdleTime 0
        <Directory "/path/to/redmine/site/public">
                PassengerEnabled on
                AllowOverride
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My apology for a stupid question. Should PassengerPoolIdleTime to be configured inside a VirtualHost for each VirtualHost or should this be setup globally?

Comment: As far as I recall you can do it globally, but I would recommend setting it per virtual host. Depending on the application, it's use, and how much it get's hit a different idle time might be more appropriate for different sites to save resources.

Comment: This made a HUGE difference on our server! Thanks James!

Comment: The problem with this config is, the server will probably not restart. Do mind the context of the Passenger configuration options. PassengerPoolIdleTime should be set in the server context (httpd.conf or apache.conf usually) https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerpoolidletime

Comment: @AdamKalisz While I agree that this is probably not the best answer then or now, I'd be worried if there were still issues like this 6 years later that haven't been solved or have better solutions written