# Redmine starts slow on Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, passenger, redmine

How do I get Redmine to start fast on Linux (CentOS)?

I upgraded all last week: latest Redmine, Ruby, Passenger, etc...

I tried about all I could find in the Redmine forum and other posts of getting it to speed up faster, that is: when requesting the Redmine website after a few hours being idle, it starts slow, but then it's blazing fast.

I am using Apache web server with Passenger. Below my current apache config, please some advice, as I am out of ideas:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.19/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.19
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby

# Refs:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235309/redmine-perfomance-inconsistency
# http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/31783
# This option should be 0, but has an issue: https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=904
PassengerPoolIdleTime 999999
PassengerMinInstances 2
PassengerHighPerformance on
PassengerPreStart https://myhost/redmine

PassengerMaxPoolSize 5
PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 4
PassengerStatThrottleRate 10
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0
PassengerMaxPreloaderIdleTime 0

RailsBaseURI /redmine
RailsEnv production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by setting up a cron job to request the redmine homepage every 15 minutes:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://redmine_server/ --stderr - > /dev/null
```

Comment: I ended up doing the same... :(.. Better than nothing.... I also tried the Redmine forum and many trial and errors, but no luck...